# How to pass a set of values for IN clause to pg_execute() arrays

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, php-pgsql

I pass to a function an array of categories and I want to make this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM trans   
        WHERE id_user = $1 AND id_cat IN ($2)";

$value = array($id_user, implode(",", $categories));

$resource = pg_prepare($db, "get_trans", $sql);
$resource = pg_execute($db, "get_trans", $value);
```

But pg_execute gives me an error

```
Warning: pg_execute(): Query failed: ERRORE: sintassi di input non    valida per il tipo integer: "1,3,5,2,4,6,7" in /var/www/html/progetto-bd/application/function.php on line 370
```

Comment: To get English error messages in your Postgres session: `set lc_messages = 'C';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`IN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19648) construct requires a **row** or a **set**, not an array.
If you pass an array, use an [**`ANY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19686) construct.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   trans   
WHERE  id_user = $1 AND id_cat = ANY ($2);
```

Also, a Postgres array literal has the form `'{elem1,elem2}'`. (Note the curly braces.)

And you need to pass *both* parameters, like @toto21 already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have two values distincts : `$id_user` (string) and list categories separate by comma (string after implode) your array `$value` should contain only two values.
Try this :

```
$str_categories = implode(",", $categories);
$arr_value = array($id_user, $str_categories);
$resource = pg_prepare($db, "get_trans", $sql);
$resource = pg_execute($db, "get_trans", $arr_value);
```